# angularjs how to change route but not reload and without history

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 url (/homepage, /contact-us, /detail) and I'm using ui-router.

From homepage (/homepage), I click detail link (/detail), then I click contact-us link, a popup is shown, url is changed to /contact-us and browser doesn't reload. Last, I close contact popup to back detail. How to click back button of browser, it back to homepage (/homepage) but not contact (/contact-us)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $state.go('where.ever.you.want.to.go'); on your popup's close button click. This should serve your purpose.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Let me try.